# I have two MariaDb images in Docker but one configuration

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I build a configuration with docker-compose :

`db:
  build:
    context: ./context
    dockerfile: /path/Dockerfile
  image: mariadb:dev`

In Dockerfile :

`FROM mariadb:latest
MAINTAINER Billy 
COPY ./ /var/lib/mysql`

After launch docker-compose up i have:

`REPOSITORY          TAG
mariadb             dev
mariadb             latest`

Why i have a image mariadb:latest and not only mariadb:dev ?

Thanks you for your help (i am a noob in docker and sorry for my english)

Answer (score 1):

```
db:
  build:
    context: ./context
    dockerfile: /path/Dockerfile
  image: mariadb:dev
```

This tells Docker that you want to build an image and call it `mariadb` and tag it as `dev` (=mariadb:dev).

Your Dockerfile is based on the image `mariadb` with its tag `latest` (`FROM mariadb:latest`).

So Docker first has to pull `mariadb:latest` from the docker hub. After that step this image is in your local registry. After building your image (`mariadb:dev`) this image is also in your local registry.

This is why you have both in your registry. `mariadb:latest` is the base image for your image. So Docker has to pull that image in the first step of your Dockerfile. And so it is in your registry.

That behaviour is documented in the official [Docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#build)

> If you specify image as well as build, then Compose names the built
>   image with the webapp and optional tag specified in image:

```
build: ./dir 
image: webapp:tag
```

> This results in an image named webapp
>   and tagged tag, built from ./dir.

I think what you really want is to use the `mariadb:latest` image from the docker hub and include your modified files as a volume instead of building a new image.

This would look like something like the follwing in your `docker-compose.yml` (please refer to the [docs of the maria db image](https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb) on how to use it in detail):

```
db:
   image: mariadb:latest
   volumes:
      - "<relativePath>:/var/lib/mysql"
   environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
```

where `<relativePath>` is the relative path from the location where your docker-compose.yml is located / where you execute the `docker-compose up`. You could for example create a sub folder "mysql" containing all the files you want to be mounted to `/var/lib/mysql` inside the container and then use `- "mysql:/var/lib/mysql"`. (By using `.` instead you will mount `docker-compose.yml` and everything inside the same folder into `/var/lib/mysql` inside the container)

Comment: Thanks sir, but if i replace "image: mariadb:dev" by "image: mariadb:latest" i keep my 2 images with same name:tag ? my configuration it's correct or does it exist a better practice ? Thanks

Comment: As a tag is unique within an image name what happens if you tell docker to call your built image `mariadb` and tag it as `latest` is: the original mariadb:latest (from docker hub) will lose its tag in your local registry. And your build image will we tag as latest. So after `docker-compose up` you will have the mariadb:latest from the docker hub (but in your registry it will be the image with name `mariadb` and no tag (`<none>`) and your personal built image will be in your local registry as `mariadb` with tag `latest`.

Comment: I think what you really want is to use the mariadb:latest image from the docker hub instead of building a new image. I will update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You have both those images because `mariadb:latest` is an intermediate image for your custom image - it's necessary to have it before executing your two custom layers (`MANTAINER` and `COPY`, respectively).

Think of your custom image as a stack of images:

- The `mariadb:latest` image from Docker Hub (I assume) is stacked first
- A `MANTAINER` intermediate layer (`MANTAINER Billy`) comes next
- A `COPY` intermediate layer (`COPY ./ /var/lib/mysql`) comes last

Then, docker creates a tag (`mariadb:dev`) and points it to your newly created image.

So, more specifically, Docker needs to have `mariadb:latest` in its local cache to make it possible for your image to be built.

You can find more information about this in [the official Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/).